# Getting attribute values that are between two numbers

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm working on a school assignment and I've been completely stumped with this step.

I need to find the sum of all elements who attribute value falls between two numbers, in this case greater than 9 and less than 18. I've spent an hour trying different combinations and done of them work, I can't find any example in the book which has this. Can someone help point out what I'm doing wrong or nudge me i the right direction?

Here's the snippet of the XML and XSLT.

```
<course>
 <par holeNumber="1">4</par>
 <par holeNumber="2">4</par>
 <par holeNumber="3">5</par>
 <par holeNumber="4">3</par>
 <par holeNumber="5">4</par>
 <par holeNumber="6">4</par>
 <par holeNumber="7">5</par>
 <par holeNumber="8">3</par>
 <par holeNumber="9">4</par>
 <par holeNumber="10">4</par>
 <par holeNumber="11">5</par>
 <par holeNumber="12">4</par>
 <par holeNumber="13">3</par>
 <par holeNumber="14">4</par>
 <par holeNumber="15">5</par>
 <par holeNumber="16">4</par>
 <par holeNumber="17">3</par>
 <par holeNumber="18">4</par>
</course>

<xsl:template match="par">
<td><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="./@holeNumber">
        <td class="sub"><xsl:value-of select="sum(@holeNumber &gt; 9)" /></td>
        <td class="final"></td>" /></td>
        <td class="final"></td>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="1">

    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>

    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/course/par[@holeNumber <= 18 and 9 <= @holeNumber]
```

You can use this in your `match`, or you can use it just to get your sum:

```
sum(/course/par[@holeNumber <= 18 and 9 <= @holeNumber])
```

***NOTE: This is using `<=` instead of just `<` to get both 18 and 9. Remove the `=` if you don't want them included.***

Answer (score 1):

The following XSLT when applied to the sample input produces the desired result of 32

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:value-of select="sum(course/par[@holeNumber > 9 and @holeNumber &lt; 18])"/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: By the way - if you're using XSLT 2 then you can use lt rather than &lt;

Comment: or swap @holeNumber and 18 and use >

Comment: @DevNull - I thought about that *after* I commented :)